# NSFetchedResultsController retrieval of specific data during sorting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I've created an `NSFetchedResultsController` object & loaded it up with data from a Core Data entity (called "AssetsPartners"). This entity has many different attributes, such as `name`, `type`, `photo`, etc.. Currently, I use the `name` attribute during data fetch and this brings back everything. Now I need to be able to sort what's inside the `NSFetchedResultsController` when pressing on one of the 3 `UISegmentedControl` buttons by the 'type' attribute. The type attribute contains only 3 possible values: all, asset & **counterparty. Index 0 = "All", index 1 = "Assets", index 2 = "Counterparty"**. So when the user clicks on index 1, for instance, which is "`Assets`", I want to pull out only that type of data from my `NSFetchedResultsController` before displaying that data in the table view. How do I do this?

Here's how I create the `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    //Is there already anything in that instance variable? Not equalling to nil means there's something alreayd there. Just return it & we're done.
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }


    //IF we make it past the previous if statement, we'll have to make the previous object.
    //We need a NSFetchRequest & a sort descriptor to create a NSFetchedResultsContoller.

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest    = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity     = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AssetsPartners" inManagedObjectContext:[AppDelegate shared].managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    //Specify how the fetched objects should be sorted.
    NSSortDescriptor *assetName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]; //type //Sorts data by name. In this case by "name"'s first letter of the alphabet.
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[assetName]]; //@[fetched, assetType, dateSD];


    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                    managedObjectContext:[AppDelegate shared].managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil    //'nil' brings data back in one long list. But writing "author", for instance, would split data by work written by each different author.
                                                                               cacheName:nil];  //Not sure what this does...


    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self; //"Look to me for any of your delegate methods".

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

After I have my data, I place it into the table view:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Has to be here to be accessible by any object that requires it regarding of scope.
    AssetsPartners *items;


    //Segmented control stuff. Simply filter fetched array data rather than creating everything cell-related from scratch.
    if(_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        items = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; //Ask '_fetchedResultsController' what's at this particular indexPath right now. Also alphabetically sorts the array list.
    }
    else if(_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        //Sorts table view alphabetically.
        //[self.elements sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES]]];
    }
    else
    {

    }




    CustomTableCell *aCell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"]; //Cells are dequeued & reused.
    if (aCell == nil)
    {
        aCell = [[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];


        UILabel *label  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65.0, 15.0, 150.0, 30.0)];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.tag       = 999; //Neccessary to have this to by-pass scope & access this label outside this if statement (Chosen number is random).
        [aCell.contentView addSubview:label];




        //Entirely new UIImageView for every UITableViewCell (to tweak the frame size & position).
        UIImageView *newImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 15.0, 35.0, 35.0)];
        newImgView.tag          = 1000;
        [aCell.contentView addSubview:newImgView];
    }


    //Makes sure the separator doesn't have that little gap in the beginning.
    //NOTE: This MUST be here and "_tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;" must exist inside [self extraTableViewParameter]!
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        aCell.layoutMargins                     = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        aCell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins   = NO;
    }




    /*CELL DETAILS.*/
    aCell.backgroundColor           = [UIColor clearColor];
    aCell.textLabel.textColor       = [UIColor clearColor];
    aCell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];


    /*FILL CELL WITH DATA.*/
    aCell.textLabel.text        = @"";
    NSInteger anInteger         = [items.balance integerValue];
    aCell.detailTextLabel.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ P", [self addWhitespacesTo:anInteger]];


    UILabel *label  = (UILabel *)[aCell.contentView viewWithTag:999]; //Casting UILabel to access the previously created one.
    label.text      = items.name;


    //1 - Reduce 'photo' characters to bare essentials. Which is just an image name.
    NSString *iconName      = [self cutOutString:@"bizzer://" fromString:items.photo]; //Get rid of "bizzer://" from string value.

    //2 - Utilize previously created UIImageView for this cell with the image name.
    UIImageView *imgView    = (UIImageView *)[aCell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
    imgView.image           = [UIImage imageNamed:iconName];
    [self turnIcon:imgView toColor:items.color];

    return aCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update fetchRequest `NSPredicate` associated with `NSFetchResultController`. Here is sample code.

```
-(void)updateFetchRequestForType:(NSString *)type
{
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];  

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == %@",type];
    [_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {   
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
    }
    [table reloadData];
}
```

**Note:** Set your cacheName to **Root** While initializing NSFetchResultController in your code.

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

(This isn't a good solution, but I leave it here for others to see why and spare them the frustration).

I solved it this way. I'm acutely aware this isn't the most elegant solution, but it works for me. Whilst it might not be ideal, I'm trying to help and I'm very willing to learn better techniques.

Create a property for your NSPredicate and give it a default value (like "All" or whatever seems appropriate for you).

- Assign the predicate to your fetchedResultsController.

Create an action for your Segmented Control which does the following when the value changes:

- Assign the new desired value to your NSPredicate
- Set the fetchedResultsController to nil (self.fetchedResultsController = nil;)
- Call the fetchedResultsController ([self fetchedResultsController];)
- Reload the data ([self.tableView reloadData];)

Comment: this isn't good solution since you have to assign nil in fetchResultController and create new instance every time, NSFetchResultController is able to sustain predicate changes.